What is correct way to create Mongo composite index for old collections in java
I need to create compoundIndex for dynamic mongodb collection.
@Document(collection = "#{@tenant}_transactions")
@CompoundIndexes({
@CompoundIndex(name = "transaction_index", def = "{'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 1}", background = true)
})

But how can I handle the cases where collections are already present.
I can give the scripts but I need to understand if there is any programmatic way to do that

You can create indexes programmatically using Spring MongoTemplate in a bean triggered on Spring Boot application startup.
@Component
public class IndexRegitar{
@Autowired
private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

  @EventListener(ApplicationStartedEvent.class)
  public void ensureIndexes(){
    mongoTemplate.indexOps(<index name>).ensureIndex(<index definition>)
  }
}



I do not have the knowlegde of tenant on application startup

It's not mandatory to create indexes on application startup, it was just an example. It's up to you to call ensureIndexes() when it is ok for you, just remove @EventListener declaration in this case.
